# RSpec 2.7 and hash should have_key

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to figure out why a very simple "does this hash have this key" spec I'm writing is failing.  Going into my Ruby REPL I am trying the following...

```
[3] pry(main)> a_hash = {:a=>"A"}
=> {:a=>"A"}
[4] pry(main)> a_hash.should have_key :a
NoMethodError: undefined method `have_key' for main:Object
from (pry):4:in `<main>'
[5] pry(main)> a_hash.keys.length.should == 1
=> true
[8] pry(main)> a_hash.has_key? :a
=> true
```

The first test is obviously what I want to get working and the second test I'm running just to verify that RSpec is loaded in my REPL environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually do this inside an RSpec example, I don't think you can write that kind of code anywhere.

```
describe "" do
  it "has a key" do
     ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree but there is a nice gem I haven't tried yet but looks promising. https://github.com/amatsuda/interactive_rspec

Comment: I originally wrote my spec in a `blah_spec.rb` file wrapped in a `des/it` block and ruby complained `undefined method `have_key' for #<Class:0x007fc0a5dd3160> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: D'oh!  I was actually missing the `it` block, I was doing it straight in the `describe`... and now it works!

Answer (score 22):

You can actually have RSpec matchers outside "it" blocks. You just need to include RSpec::Matchers.

```
[ ~/work/mobile_server (master)]$ irb
>> require 'rspec'
true
>> include RSpec::Matchers
Object < BasicObject
>> {a: 1}.should have_key(:a)
true
```

Comment: I think this is definitely the better/more informative answer. Thanks for the info @Costi.

Comment: In RSpec 3 you should type "expect({a: 1}).to have_key(:a)"